# How do i pass result of callback into variable and access the var freely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know there's a ton of question similar to my question, but i didn't see any good case to help me,

I have a callback from native function bridge and this how i used it on JS:

```
getAllParameter((data)=>{
  console.log(data) // data is Javascript Object
})
```

I've tried this to get the value of `data`:

```
getAllParameter((data)=>{
  return new Promise((resolve)=> resolve(showToken(data.Token)))
})

async function showToken(token){
  var res = await token
  return res
}

var isiToken = showToken()
console.log("isiToken")
console.log(isiToken)
```

but the result is:

```
isiToken
{ _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }
```

i don't know whats wrong with my code, i want to get the value of `data` outside of the `getAllParameter`, how can i do that properly?

the reason why i need to get the result of `getAllParameter` and used it freely is because I've `token` value inside the `data`, and i need to use the token in `axios` instance config

so the full code of my file should be:

```js
getAllParameter((data)=>{
  return new Promise((resolve)=> resolve(showToken(data.Token)))
})

async function showToken(token){
  var res = await token
  console.log("res")
  console.log(res)
  return res
}

var isiToken = showToken()
console.log("isiToken")
console.log(isiToken)

const http = Axios.create ({
  baseURL: Constants.APILink,
  timeout: Constants.Timeout,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer '+isiToken}

export default http
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of your `getAllParameter` definition but that method should be calling your callback at the end. Hoping that it does that, here is snippet that does what you want

```
(function() {
   var data;
   function getAllParam(callback) {
      console.log("getAllParam");
      callback("getAllParam");
   }
   getAllParam((data)=> {
      this.data = data);
      console.log(this.data);
   });
})();
```

So, what I am doing is

1. Creating a variable called data;
2. Assigning the callback response to my data variable. (Read closures & this in arrow functions)
3. Use that later.

But here is the limitation with my code: This doesn't work when `getAllParam` is an async function. Meaning if the callback is not called in sequence. You have to use promises then.

**EDIT**

`app.js`

```
function getAllParam(callback) {
    console.log("getAllParam");
    callback({Token: "getAllParam"});
}

var httpPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    getAllParam((data) => {
        let token = data.Token;
        console.log("Creating http from here using token");
        let http = Axios.create({ bearer: token});

        resolve(http);
    })
});

export default httpPromise;
```

`file_that_imports_app_js.js`

```
import httpPromise from "./app.js";
async function init() {
    let http = await httpPromise;

    http.get("/", ...)
}

init();
```

Comment: does `console.log(this.data)` printing `getAllParam`? and actually my `getAllParam` is async so i need to wait till `getAllParam` has finish the job

Comment: The callback of getAllParam should do the console.log and not outside the scope if your getAllParam is async. If you write your code in the same scope as getAllParam, your code will be executed even before the control is passed.

Comment: @flix Okay, I understand that you want to resolve the token and use it in another API and finally give that response to be exported. You can't do this. You need to change in the file that imports this file also to resolve. You can't form a timeline with your requirements unless your import of this file is changed. I am editing code this.

Comment: **You need to change in the file that imports this file also to resolve** how can i do that?

Comment: I have  an error `undefined is not a function (evaluating '_Axiosx.default.post('User/CheckCurrentLogin', item)')`, what should i do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190075/discussion-between-mani-and-flix).